# css vs dreamweaver templates

Tags: css, templates, ftp, indexing, dreamweaver

what is the difference in performance between css templates and dreamweaver templates , or are they the same. Need to know which one gets indexed quicker by google. 
I want to move my website to one the best templates for quick uploads and ftp linkups with linkmanagement tools

please advise
thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is why I despise Dreamweaver and the alike...

Dreamweaver creates websites, which consist of HTML and CSS code, and maybe some JavaScript.

- **HTML**: the "glue". It's the structure which browsers read.
- **CSS**: the "perty stuff". It's what browsers read to determine how to make your page look (colors, layout, etc.).

Since Dreamweaver makes websites, a Dreamweaver template also helps Dreamweaver to make websites, which implies that it follows the above structure.

Templates just style your site and might provide some basic functionality, so they have nothing to do with uploads. Some might be bloated and cause slow loading times, but that's dependent upon the template.

In the end, *Dreamweaver Template is more or less CSS + HTML*.

Answer (score 0):

A DW template file helps to isolate parts of your HTML code on a page/page basis. Editable content and "locked" content together (in hopes of making development quicker). If you like DW, and have a template you like - 0use it. But don't expect that to be your silver bullet.

There's no advantage to either template where search engines are concerned (good/bad content withstanding).

Content...(pertinent content) is what Google is after. Having a 1M file of valid content will beat a 200k file of sparse/bait-n-switch content every time (well, it's supposed to, right?).

Answer (score 0):

**The answer you are looking for:** Every Dreamweaver template is a CSS+HTML template. So it depends on the CSS template you are using. For the most part Dreamweaver is pretty bad about writing optimal CSS and it also uses inline styles which is bad for performance.

**The real answer:** It is obvious you are a beginner and don't know how silly your question is, it is not even one question, and is open ended and has no answer. There is no such thing as a CSS template, CSS by itself is not enough to create a template and this is just a marketing word to use to sell templates to people looking for such a thing as a better alternative to HTML templates, and etc, there is CSS for a certain type of template or certain Document Object Model, so if that is your definition of a CSS template than every Dreamweaver Template is a CSS template, as Dreamweaver itself is not a web technology or language. Dreamweaver is a WYSIWYG/IDE that helps you to write CSS (and other code) without knowledge of CSS, or in my case I use it because I love the pink/purple syntax highlighting it has for CSS in code view.

****Need to know which one gets indexed quicker by google - FTP Upload - linkmanagement ****

This has nothing to do with your question, you can create a website in notepad that gets better SEO results. You are mixing all these different concepts together, SEO, CSS, HTML Templates, google indexing,templates, quick uploads, ftp linkups, linkmanagement tools, these are all different concepts and each require years of experience for you to achieve this. At the end of the day what I am trying to tell you is, building a website as you describe is not a few clicks to create a template with dreamweaver. You first need to learn enough to be able to ask the right questions. And then you will be able to create such a website, not the best and ultimate "templates for quick uploads and ftp linkups with linkmanagement tools" but something that works, even though I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to build.

**I Think you should look into a CMS like WordPress and get a nice looking wordpress template for your site and eventually become more familiar with these concepts. WordPress has a really good SEO/(google indexing as you say) that it even gets better results than expensive websites built by professionals. This is definitely what you want! trust me!
http://wordpress.org/**